# Creating an array of Dates for the next 4 sunday (start of weeks)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Looking a creating a simple spinner in Android that will have 4 values loaded for the next 4 dates of the coming Sundays.

Making a simple app to quickly "punch in" my schedule to my calendar in a new way while getting more familiar in programming.

I've found ways to load all the days/etc into an array but onCreate I want it to only load the next 4 sundays.  So it would not allow me to go backwards or too far forward in the year.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, how you can create an array of Dates for the next 4 Sundays:

```
List<Date> datesList = new ArrayList<Date>();

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
   c.add(Calendar.DATE,7);
   Date sunday = c.getTime();
   datesList.add(sunday);
}
```